# How to replace string in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML:

```
<path>/en/products/bike</path>
```

Is there an XSLT function that will return

```
/products/bike
```

?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are the criteria you want to match on?  Do you want the substring starting from the fourth character, the substring following `/en`, following the second forward slash, the second-to-last slash, etc?  There are many ways to extract that particular substring, but some will presumably be more useful to you than others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `substring-after` function.

So, for example, the following XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="path">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '/en')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your XML:

```
<path>/en/products/bike</path>
```

will give:

```
/products/bike
```

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT 2.0 you can also use the **[replace()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace)** function, which accepts a regex pattern as the second parameter and an optional 4th parameter for regex flags.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="path">
        <xsl:sequence select="replace(., '^/en','')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```